# Web API Self hosting from a test assembly

Tags: asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I'm currently evaluating WebAPI and NancyFx for a new project about to start. I've managed to get Nancy to self host from a test assembly (by itself it uses asp.net hosting).

Is there any way to do the same with Web API? I would like to keep the web api project hosted on IIS, but i would like to spin it up from my test assembly, so i can run tests against it.

I have found some blogposts on how to use Autofac to scan controllers from another assembly (seems a little backwards only to get hosting from another assembly to work, but if it can be done, i guess that would be an option), but i would like to keep using Structuremap ioc for this project.

Comment: Does this question cover what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676828/using-nunit-to-perform-integration-tests-with-asp-net-webapi-controllers specifically the strathweb link (integration testing with in memory hosting)

Comment: Would you tell me how you got to get nancy to self host your test assembly please? I'm trying exactly the opposite. I have a self hosted project and I'm trying to get another project (ASP.NET hosted) to host it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to get it working with help from [Mark Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440706/mark-jones) [link](http://forums.asp.net/post/4846132.aspx). This is what i ended up with in my test assembly.

```
    private static HttpSelfHostServer _server;

    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void Setup()
    {
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(Settings.TestUri);
        WebApiConfig.Register(config); //map routes
        IocConfig.Bootstrap(config); //configure dependency injection
        _server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
        _server.OpenAsync().Wait();
    }

    [AfterTestRun]
    public static void TearDown()
    {
        _server.CloseAsync().Wait();
    }
```